# show Google Adsense when adblock enabled

Tags: adsense, adblock

well i searched a lot for this but got no result but i have seen a website where this is being happening. In File hippo Website Google Ads are appearing even when ad blocker is enabled.So can someone please tell me the way to do the same , so that i can enable ad sense even when ad blocker is enabled.

How to similarly show adsense ads even when adblocker is enabled . any help will be great.

[Ad sense Ads Appear Even When Ad blocker is enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqUga.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Filehippo is in Adblock's "white list". Go to the extension options, uncheck "Allow some non-intrusive advertising" and it will block it.